# RVM - Not able to use gems from the @global gemset

Tags: rubygems, rvm

I'm having an issue with RVM. In general I use project specific gemsets; however, recently when I install a gem into the @global gemset, it is not available when I'm working in a particular project. Here is an example where I was trying to install the *hpricot* gem. This is right after installing the gem and starting a fresh shell.

```
$ rvm use ruby-1.9.2
Using /home/bshaver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180

$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.0.12)
hpricot (0.8.4)
rake (0.8.7)

$ rvm use ruby-1.9.2@myproject-gems
Using /home/bshaver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180 with gemset myproject-gems

$ gem list | grep hpricot

$ rvm info

ruby-1.9.2-p180@myproject-gems:

  system:
uname:       "Linux hawkeye.localdomain 2.6.35.12-88.fc14.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Mar 31 21:21:57 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.1.7(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)"
zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
version:      "rvm 1.5.2 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"

  ruby:
interpreter:  "ruby"
version:      "1.9.2p180"
date:         "2011-02-18"
platform:     "x86_64-linux"
patchlevel:   "2011-02-18 revision 30909"
full_version: "ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-linux]"

  homes:
gem:          "/home/bshaver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@myproject-gems"
ruby:         "/home/bshaver/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180"

  binaries:
ruby:         "/home/bshaver/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby"
irb:          "/home/bshaver/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/irb"
gem:          "/home/bshaver/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/gem"
rake:         "/home/bshaver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/bin/rake"

  environment:
PATH:         "/home/bshaver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@myproject-gems/bin:/home/bshaver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/bin:/home/bshaver/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin:/home/bshaver/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/java/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/real/RealPlayer/:/home/bshaver/bin:/home/bshaver/test-root/bin:/home/bshaver/Documents/scripts/"
GEM_HOME:     "/home/bshaver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@myproject-gems"

GEM_PATH:     "/home/bshaver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@myproject-gems:/home/bshaver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global"
MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/bshaver/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180"
IRBRC:        "/home/bshaver/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/.irbrc"
RUBYOPT:      ""
gemset:       "myproject-gems"
```

Any ideas why *hpricot* would not be available inside of the project gemset? I did have the same issue with *bundler* as well, but ended up installing it again in the gemset.

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that I wasn't using the **@global** gemset when installing hpricot gem the first time.

There is a difference between the interpreter's default gemset and the **@global** gemset for that interpreter.

So you can achieve the desired result by

```
$ rvm use ruby-1.9.2@global
Using /home/bshaver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180 with gemset global

$ gem install validation_refelection
Fetching: validation_reflection-1.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed validation_reflection-1.0.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for validation_reflection-1.0.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for validation_reflection-1.0.0...

$ rvm use ruby-1.9.2@myproject-gems
Using /home/bshaver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180 with gemset myproject-gems

$ gem list | grep validation_reflection
validation_reflection (1.0.0)
```

And the gem is available to the project as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same thing and did some experimenting

```
$ gem list

...
tzinfo (0.3.29, 0.3.28)
uglifier (1.0.0)
wirble (0.1.3)
```

Then in the debugger console (requires gem `ruby-debug` for ruby 1.8.7 or `ruby-debug19` for ruby 1.9.2):

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > puts `gem list`  #note that those are not quotes, but backticks

...
tzinfo (0.3.28)
wirble (0.1.3)
 => nil
```

Everything listed in `gem list` was a gem from the gemfile or one of its dependencies.  I believe Rails calls Bundler to create the gem context before launching the application.  I need to be more reading to be sure of this, but this is what appears to be the case.

So for your situation, add `gem 'hpricot'` to your gemfile and you should be able to use it in the context of the project.

Comment: Thanks Eric for the response. If I understand correctly what your saying, its not working for me. When I add 'hpricot' to the Gemfile, then it should pass the `bundle check`, but it comes back with **Your Gemfile's dependencies could not be satisfied** even though the missing gem is installed _somewhere_ in the GEM_PATH.

Comment: You still have to run `bundle install` after adding this to your gemfile.  I believe bundler creates a separate context for each project and will only check those folders.  Gems that are installed with `gem install <gemname>` aren't available until you put them in the gemfile and run `bundle install`.

Comment: Ah, but running `bundle install` installs a 2nd instance of the missing gems into the project specific gemset. According to the RVM reference, the [@global](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/gemsets/global/) should allow the single copy of the gem to be shared between projects. However, while I was looking to find the 2 directories where my gem was getting installed, the answer presented itself, as the first installation directory was not under the **@global** gemset.